# Google translate.detect crashes after Proguard

Tags: android, proguard

It works well with debug version but it crashes in release version after Proguard.

Here is the code that crashes

```
TranslateOptions options = TranslateOptions.newBuilder()
                .setApiKey(context.getString(R.string.google_api_key))
                .build();
        Translate translate = options.getService();
        Detection detection = translate.detect(sourceText);
```

Last line crashes.

Here is Proguard rule

```
-keep class com.google.**
-keep interface com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
```

Comment: Did you find solution to your problem? I am using Translation Api and facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check Proguard Config section.

https://medium.com/@amsanjeev/adding-translate-api-to-android-apps-788c5bca5521

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
 @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault


-dontwarn org.joda.convert.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.auto.**
-dontwarn autovalue.shaded.com.**
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn javax.lang.model.element.Modifier
```